# SQL: include values in filter but not restricted to

Tags: sql, select

I have certain rows in the database, say `customer_id in ('c7', 'c77', 'c777')`, that I want to be included in my query result which I will use as a sample as well as for testing purposes. At the same time, I want the returned result to contain as many as 10,000 rows, however, the specified `customer_id` filter may contain only about 100 rows.

Is there an SQL feature or syntax (of any flavor, if such exist) that includes the rows I am looking for plus the remainder from limit (randomly or chosen according to SQL's default), contained in a single `SELECT` statement, without using `UNION`?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Have you tried SELECT statement with "AND" ??

Comment: Honestly I'm using Dremel, but since I'm a complete noob in Dremel and RDBMS SQL is what I know, that's why I ask it first if such exist in RDBMS realm, then maybe try if it works in Dremel as well.

Comment: Do you want the result to **always** contain 10000 rows, even if the filter wouldn't select that many?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I use the searched data set to verify correctness of the created visualization like aggregates, grouping, etc.

Comment: And what should those additional rows contain? Where should the values come from? Do you want to repeat the found rows a 1000 times?

Comment: Normally, you'd use `UNION ALL` for this. What's the problem with `UNION`?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov No problem with `UNION`. I just wonder if such feature exists. `UNION` is okay esp. if there is Common Table Expression, unfortunately, Dremel SQL does not have CTE.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you didn't specify you DBMS, so for `ORACLE`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM Customers c
    WHERE c.customer_id in('c7','cc7',.......)
)WHERE rownum <= 10000;
```

For `SQL-Server` :

```
SELECT TOP 10000 *
FROM Customers c
WHERE c.customer_id in('c7','cc7',.......);
```

For `MySQL` :

```
FROM Customers c
WHERE c.customer_id in('c7','cc7',.......)
LIMIT 10000;
```

This will select the first 10000 rows with the ID's listed in the `IN()` statement, according to the DBMS default. You can add an `order by` clause to each one of them to specify which 10K records you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could query all the rows, order them by whether or not they fit this condition, and limit the returned result.

**MySQL**:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     customers
ORDER BY CASE WHEN customer_id IN ('c7', 'c77', 'c777') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC
LIMIT    10000
```

**MS SQL Server**:

```
SELECT   TOP 10000 *
FROM     customers
ORDER BY CASE WHEN customer_id IN ('c7', 'c77', 'c777') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC
```

**Oracle 12c:**

```
SELECT   *
FROM     customers
ORDER BY CASE WHEN customer_id IN ('c7', 'c77', 'c777') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC
FETCH    FIRST 10000 ROWS ONLY
```

**ANSI SQL with window functions:**

```
SELECT   *
FROM     (SELECT *, 
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                     (ORDER BY CASE 
                               WHEN customer_id IN ('c7', 'c77', 'c777') THEN 1 
                               ELSE 0 END DESC) rn
          FROM   customers) t
WHERE    rn <= 10000
```